# Why is $\int_{a}^{b} 3x^2 \,dx$ equal to $ b^{3} - a^{3} $

Tags: integration, probability-theory

My book on probability theory says that:
$$ P([a,b]) = \int_{a}^{b} 3x^2 \,dx = b^{3} - a^{3} $$
I never paid much attention to integrals, but it is surprising to me that $b^{3} - a^{3}$ perfectly gives the area under the curve for a function like $3x^{2}$ which does not have a exponent of $3$. Can anyone explain why that makes sense?

Comment: What is your question? Is it why the integral equals to $b^3-a^3$ or why does Probability theory gives it?

Comment: Why it is the integral. I think I get the probability part because with a=0, and b=1 the integral equals one, so that part sort of makes sense.
What I am slightly confused about is how they reach $b^{3} - a^{3}$ not sure what the derivation is.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral

Comment: i'm assuming this probability course requires a couple of semesters of calculus. if you are self learning, i'd recommend at least like a companion textbook, as you are likely to interact a lot with this material in your probability course.

Comment: @DavidP thanks for the advice, it is for a university course starting next week. I just never really had anything about integrals, but I'll try to find a good cheat sheet and maybe read some introduction chapter about integrals in a calculus book, maybe that's a good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, if $F(x)$ is an antiderivative of $3x^2$, then$$\int_a^b3x^2\,\mathrm dx=F(b)-F(a).\tag1$$But you can take $F(x)=x^3$, which *is* an antiderivative of $3x^2$. Then, $(1)$ tells you that$$\int_a^b3x^2\,\mathrm dx=b^3-a^3.$$